# Contactor control circuit

Tags: capacitor, relay

I am trying to understand a contactor control circuit that I took apart from a broken GIGAVAC GX14BAB.

Here is a list of parts that I think are the closest representation of what is on the PCB:

- C1:

  - Capacitance unknown
- R1:

  - SMD 104
  - 100 kOhm
- R2:

  - SMD 512
  - 5.1 kOhm
- D1:

  - SMD WX104
  - Device Type bi-directional TVS diode [SMAJ10A](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS-Diode_SMAJ-23503.pdf)
- D2 and D4:

  - SMD YR103
  - Device Type bi-directional TVS diode [SMAJ40A](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS-Diode_SMAJ-23503.pdf)
- D3:

  - SMD RZ102
  - Device Type uni-directional TVS diode [SMAJ100A](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS-Diode_SMAJ-23503.pdf)
- Q1:

  - N-channel MOSFET [FQP16N25C](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FQ/FQPF16N25C.pdf)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1y0C.png]

The coils were missing from the contactor, so I'm not sure what P1, P2, and P3 are connected to, but my best guess is that P1 connectors to the primary coil, P2 is ground, and P3 connects to the secondary coil.  From the data sheet:

> Contactor has two coils. Both are used for pick-up, and 
>   then in approximately 75 milliseconds, one coil is electronically 
>   removed from the coil drive circuit.

Electrical engineering is not my strongest suit, my best guess at this circuit is that C1, R1, and R2 governs how fast the secondary coil gets shut down. R1 and R2 is a voltage divider for the Q1 MOSFET.  When the voltage is at a suitable level after 75ms, the drain and source will connect and ground the secondary coil.  Am I correct with this guess?

Also, can I calculate the capacitance of C1 by using the 75ms as the time constant:

```
75ms = R * C = 100k * 0.75u
```

to estimate the value as 0.75 uF?

Finally, are the purposes of the diodes mainly for circuit protection and voltage clamping?  Here's an image of the PCB.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/swmAh.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet, it appears as there are two terminals connected externally, and they are X1+ and X2-.

So say P1 is +12 and P3 is the return. Probably the hold coil is connected from P1 to P3 and the pull-in coil from P1 to P2.

When 12V is sharply applied to P1 (remember P3 is the return) the gate voltage on the MOSFET rises to 12V, turning it on, and energizing the high current pull-in coil through the MOSFET and D3 (forward biased). The capacitor (probably 1uF) discharges through R1 until the MOSFET turns off and the pull-in coil de-energizes.

The purpose of D2 and D4 is to absorb inductive spikes from the coils. D3 prevents destruction of the pull-in coil if the input polarity is reversed. D1 protects the MOSFET gate from overvoltage.

Edit: See schematic below (drawn more conventionally).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKhYvn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I didn't realize I drew D3 incorrectly, it makes a lot more sense now.